# Excel VBA - Creating Scatter Plot Issues

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I haven't used excel VBA before, and I'm finding it a bit frustrating compared to octave/MATLAB..

Anywho, at the moment I'm trying to do something pretty basic.

1. Take user defined cell values and assign them to variables within VBA code
2. Create an output array and an x-axis array to record values to plot
3. For loop through an equation while recording the values and inserting them into respective arrays
4. scatterplot the output array vs the x-axis array

The code I've done so far is below. The scatter plot attempt creates the X-axis correctly from what I can tell, but I only get 1 point on the y-axis, which is the last data value in the Ion() array.

What am I missing to plot the entire Ion array?

```
Private Sub Generate_Ip_vs_time_Click()
  
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 
 Dim Tsw As Double
 Dim Don As Double
 Dim Lp As Double
 Dim Vin_min As Double
 Dim Imax As Double
 Dim upperBound As Double
 Dim i As Double
 
 Tsw = Range("C38").Value
 Don = Range("T26").Value
 Lp = Range("O29").Value / 1000000
 Vin_min = Range("C32").Value
 Imax = Range("O32").Value
 lowerbound = 0.0000001
 upperBound = Tsw

Dim Ion() As Double
Dim Xvalue_x() As Double

ReDim Ion(lowerbound To upperBound)
ReDim Xvalue_x(lowerbound To upperBound)

' Calculate Primary Current (Up slope)
 For i = lowerbound To upperBound Step 0.00000001
    Ion(i) = Vin_min / Lp * i
    Xvalue_x(i) = i
    Debug.Print Xvalue_x(i)
        If Ion(i) > Imax Then
        Exit For
        End If
 Next i

  Dim MyChart As Chart
  Set MyChart = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlXYScatter).Chart


With MyChart
 .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
 
       With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Values = Ion
            .XValues = Xvalue_x
            .MarkerStyle = -4168
            .MarkerSize = 5
        End With
        
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "Ip vs time(s)"

End With

End Sub
```

EDIT:

added this to my code:

```
ReDim Ion(lowerbound To upperBound)
ReDim Xvalue_x(lowerbound To upperBound)

' Calculate Primary Current (Up slope)
 For i = lowerbound To upperBound Step 0.00000001
    Ion(i) = Vin_min / Lp * i
    Xvalue_x(i) = i
'added the 2 debug statements below
    **Debug.Print Xvalue_x(i)
    Debug.Print Ion(i)**
        If Ion(i) > Imax Then
        Exit For
        End If
 Next i


'Added the below debug statements
**Debug.Print Tsw
Debug.Print Don
Debug.Print Lp
Debug.Print Vin_min
Debug.Print Imax**

  Dim MyChart As Chart
  Set MyChart = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlXYScatter).Chart
```

What I get in the immediate window is the following:

It makes sense the two values outputting together, since those are the in the for loop. I deleted a lot of the earlier values only to show where the if statement kicks in. What doesn't make sense to me is why the 5 debug statements I added are looping as well. But, idk if that's the immediate "now" issue or not.

4.87999999999996E-06

1.30831099195709

4.88999999999996E-06

1.31099195710455

4.89999999999996E-06

1.313672922252

4.90999999999996E-06

1.31635388739945

4.91999999999996E-06

1.31903485254691

4.92999999999996E-06

1.32171581769436

0.0000125

0.4

0.000373

100

1.32024128686327

0.0000125

0.4

0.000373

100

1.32024128686327

0.0000125

0.4

0.000373

100

1.32024128686327

0.0000125

0.4

0.000373

100

1.32024128686327

The current scatterplot I'm getting is below:
[Ip vs Time Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6wF3.png)

So after listening to Tin Williams, and seeing he was right about indexing, all I did was change the following to map it out. The only issue with this is the scaling factor is hardcoded, but that can be easily changed.
[Code that works and gives what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMM4V.png)

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you provided sample values for `Tsw`, `Don`, `Lp`, `Vin_min`, and `Imax`?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure really how to do that, do you want me to use this statement (Debug.Print Variable) for each one?

Comment: Meaning, we don't have your workbook, so you could [edit] your question with the values in those cells.

Comment: Array indexes in VBA must be whole numbers. Eg; `Dim arr(0.1 to 0.5)` will run without any error, but your array upper and lower bounds will both be zero.   `Dim arr(0.1 to 0.6)` will give you 0 and 1 as bounds.

Comment: @BigBen I've updated the question to show values that the immediate window shows

Comment: @TimWilliams are you positive? If that was the case I don't believe my x-axis would correctly be showing like it is, I updated my question with the scatterplot hyperlink showing at the end

Comment: If fractional indexes were possible how would VBA know how many elements to reserve for the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array bounds and indexes in VBA must be whole numbers.  If you try to use fractional values they will get rounded, but will not raise an error:

For example:

```
Dim arr()

'setting bounds
ReDim arr(0.0000001 To 0.000005)
Debug.Print LBound(arr), UBound(arr)       '>> 0 0

ReDim arr(0.0000001 To 1.5)
Debug.Print LBound(arr), UBound(arr)       '>> 0 2

ReDim arr(0.0000001 To 1.49)
Debug.Print LBound(arr), UBound(arr)       '>> 0 1

'access by index
ReDim arr(1 To 3)
arr(1) = 1
arr(2) = 2
arr(3) = 3
Debug.Print arr(1.5) '>> 2   (banker's rounding)
Debug.Print arr(2.5) '>> 2
```

Maybe try a different approach (untested)

```vb
Private Sub Generate_Ip_vs_time_Click()
  
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim Tsw As Double, Don As Double, Lp As Double, Vin_min As Double, Imax As Double
    Dim n As Long
    Dim i As Double, x As Double, Ion() As Double, Xvalue_x() As Double
    
    With ActiveSheet ' or some specific sheet
        Tsw = .Range("C38").Value
        Don = .Range("T26").Value
        Lp = .Range("O29").Value / 1000000
        Vin_min = .Range("C32").Value
        Imax = .Range("O32").Value
    End With
    
    x = 0.0000001
    n = 0
    Do While x <= Tsw
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve Xvalue_x(1 To n)
        ReDim Preserve Ion(1 To n)
        Xvalue_x(n) = x
        Ion(n) = Vin_min / Lp * x
        If Ion(n) > Imax Then Exit Do
        x = x + 0.00000001
    Loop

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlXYScatter).Chart
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .values = Ion
            .XValues = Xvalue_x
            .MarkerStyle = -4168
            .MarkerSize = 5
        End With
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Ip vs time(s)"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank's sir, I updated my post to show what I changed, I'll take a look at yours to see what you did as well